# Is possible to programmatically connect to Wi-Fi network using Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Using Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android, it is possible to check if the Wi-Fi is enabled?
And, if is disabled, it's possible to enable it?
Once it's enabled, how to search and connect to a network?

Answer (score 10):

### Enable/Disable Wifi:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(WifiService);
if (!wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
    wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(true);
else 
    wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(false);
```

### Permission to change Wifi state:

```
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
```

### Add a network:

```
var networkSSID = "Stack";
var networkPass = "Overflow";
var config = new WifiConfiguration();
config.Ssid = '"' + networkSSID + '"';

// For WPA/WPA2, WEP is different (still using WEP? shame on you ;-)
config.PreSharedKey = '"' + networkPass + '"';
wifiManager.AddNetwork(config);
```

### Connect to a network:

```
IList<WifiConfiguration> myWifi = wifiManager.ConfiguredNetworks;
wifiManager.Disconnect();
wifiManager.EnableNetwork(myWifi.FindFirst(x => x.Ssid.Contains(networkSSID)), true);
wifiManager.Reconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I not implemented yet, but this solution seems very specific to Xamarin.Android. How would be for Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: @LuísRigoni you are correct, my answer is for Android, must have been blind on the iOS tag.... iOS is very restrictive on allowing access to networking. On iOS, your app is sandboxed and can not access the Wifi manager's keychain, so adding a SSID programmatically is not available, nor programmatically connecting to a SSID, you used to be able to read the current SSID, but 9.x removed that access, opening default settings was removed in iOS 5.1... For generic connectivity, I highly recommend: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Connectivity/Connectivity

Comment: I think this will also requires: `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`