# Automatically close the wifi settings page when wifi gets connected

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on an fullscreen app where all navigation is done within the app screen.Meaning that all the hardware buttons (back button, home button) are disabled.
Now i ran into a problem where i have to go to wifi settings page from the app.
Used this code to go to wifi settings page.

```
public void showSettingsPage()
    {
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ActionPickWifiNetwork);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

Now after connecting to the internet i need to automatically go back to the app without having to press any button.
I used startActivityForResult but it would only get called after pressing back button.

I thought of building own interface for getting all wifi networks and connecting to it but it seems more work. It would be better if i can use the built in settings interface and get back automatically when connected.

Comment: let the user do the connecting part and use broadcast receiver to figure when you're connected; this is usually the common approach; or just do your in app connecting thing.

Comment: Did you try to connect to Wi-Fi network programmatically?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729617/is-possible-to-programmatically-connect-to-wi-fi-network-using-xamarin