# How to force XAMARIN app to use WIFI only

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am building an app in `XAMARIN`, that has to connect to a custom device via `wifi` and that device does not have internet connection. So my app always wants to work on mobile data and there for never communicating with the device. Is there anyway to force the app to use only `WIFI` and never mobile data? I guess I'm not the only one with that problem as I've seen a few posts about this, but none in `xamarin` specific.

EDIT:
I found that if I let the application run for about 50 seconds, then it will use the wifi insted of mobile data. Is this due to some timeout? If so, then can I shorten the timeout?

Comment: For iOS , we can only set internet permission in System Setting . In Android , you could refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729617/is-possible-to-programmatically-connect-to-wi-fi-network-using-xamarin .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I'm already connecting to the device programaticly and that's not the problem. The problem is if the mobile data is enabled my Android phone automaticly starts doing stuff over mobile data insted of the wifi (because the wifi is not connected to the internet). And Android is making this type of connection a real pain in the ass.

Comment: I'm afraid it is impossible to do that  . We can only set the network in system setting .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of sweating I have found the solution. Make a class with this code:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net;

namespace Project.Communication
{
    class ForceNetworkType
    {
        public static Context _context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        /// <summary>
        /// Forces the wifi over cellular
        /// </summary>
        public static void ForceWifiOverCellular()
        {
            ConnectivityManager connection_manager = (ConnectivityManager)_context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

            NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            request.AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi);

            var callback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback();
            connection_manager.RegisterNetworkCallback(request.Build(), new CustomNetworkAvailableCallBack());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Forces the cellular over wifi.
        /// </summary>
        public static void ForceCellularOverWifi()
        {
            ConnectivityManager connection_manager = (ConnectivityManager)_context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

            NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            request.AddTransportType(TransportType.Cellular);

            connection_manager.RegisterNetworkCallback(request.Build(), new CustomNetworkAvailableCallBack());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom network available call back.
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomNetworkAvailableCallBack : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    {
        public static Context _context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        ConnectivityManager connection_manager = (ConnectivityManager)_context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

        public override void OnAvailable(Network network)
        {
            //ConnectivityManager.SetProcessDefaultNetwork(network);    //deprecated (but works even in Android P)
            connection_manager.BindProcessToNetwork(network);           //this works in Android P
        }
    }
}
```

And Then you just use where you need to force certain Network:

```
ForceNetworkType.ForceWifiOverCellular();
```

to force the wifi over mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xamarin.Essentials.
Like this:

>

```
var profiles = Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles;
if (profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi))
{
    // Active Wi-Fi connection.
}
```

You can change this check to block users that without a wifi connection.

reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.connectionprofile?view=xamarin-essentials

Answer (score -1):

I believe the best you can actually do is set the preference of what you want the device to use. With both OS, it will prefer a Wifi connection over a cellular connection unless it times out on the request.

However you can use the Reachability class in iOS to say something like:

//PseudoCode

```
if(ReachabilityStatus == ReachableViaWifi)
{
//Only do things when WIFI is on
}

else
{
//Only do things when WIFI is not on
}
```

Within Android, you can do the following with ConnectivityManager:

//PseudoCode again

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.GetNetworkInfo(ConnectivityType.Wifi);

        if (wifi.IsConnected)
        {
            //Pretty fly for a wifi
        }
        else
        {
            //No wifi here!
        }
```

Comment: That is far from solving my problem. I know when I'm connected to the wife, I do stuff when connected to the wifi, but if the mobile data is on while I'm connected to the wifi, the app will try to use the mobile data as it has internet connection.